# getting indexpath while reordering cells in tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want change the cells order in my tableview

I am using following code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath  
{    
    [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:path1 toIndexPath:path2];
}
```

here `path1` indexpath of row which user selected now I want find the indexpath of the row the user drop that cell so how can I find that toIndexPath(path2).

Comment: the moving is happened by drag-n-drop, so when the user drag the row, it provides the `fromIndexPath`, and where the user release the row, that position will be the `toIndexPath`.

Comment: how can i get toindexpath?

Comment: How u get path1? what u think what is this 3 argument tableView,(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath and (NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath ?

Comment: when the method is being called back in your delegate class the _destination_ index path is in the `toIndexPath`. could you clarify what you are exactly looking for?

Comment: @CRDave  i have given button in cell when user click on that button he can able to reorder that from ibaction of that button i am getting indexpath of that row which is path1 now i want to get that position where user release that that cell

Comment: @holex check above comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confused with the purpose of this method - this is a callback function of the UITableViewDataSource that's designed to notify the data model of changes in the table. From the docs:

> Tells the data source to move a row at a specific location in the table view to another location.
>
> The UITableView object sends this message to the data source when the user presses the reorder control in fromRow.

This means that what you need to do here is to make sure your model (Usually an array) is rearranged to sync properly with these changes.

Hope this gives you a good direction.

Comment: you are rigth i am writing this line in that delegate method
[tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:path1 toIndexPath:path2];

after removing that line i got it thankyou i got confused.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return YES;
}
```

& also:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
 //do whatever you want after the row has been moved
}
```

Here is an example of drag N drop:

https://github.com/coderDove/UITableView-Drag-n-Drop

Hope this Helps!!!

Comment: i am using two methods only

Comment: just check the link provided .... you will get the methods & funtions required for tableview to perform edit & dranNDrop